# Show and count entries in filtered table until today via EXCEL VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

as the title states, i am trying to use a filter via VBA to hide all date entries from a filtered table which are in the future and count them up, but the code just wont work any which way i tried.

My current approach is as follows:

```
Dim wbkPlanning As Workbook
Dim wksPlanning As Worksheet
Dim FilterValue as Integer

Workbooks.Open (.... Some Path...) 'this works as i have several other Autofilters in this macro that do the job just fine)

Set wbkPlanning = Workbooks("NAMEOFWORKBOOK.xlsx")
Set wksPlanning = wbkPlanning.Worksheets("NameOfWorksheet")

wksPlanning.Range("$A$4:$AS$600").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="=<" & CDbl(Date)

FilterValue = wksPlanning.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1

MsgBox FilterValue
```

When i set the filter up manually in the worksheet, the results are just fine, but when i set it up like this i get Zero results..

I am kinda stumped and would really appreciate some tips.

Thanks!

Comment: " i get Zero results" Do you mean the message box shows 0?

Comment: Yes, exactly - the Value is Zero shown in the MessageBox

Comment: OK, what I'd suggest is adding breakpoints and `debug.print` to see what values are being populated into your variables. Then in the immediate window, review the output(s). You'll then be able to work backwards from there, and understand where it's falling over.

Comment: +1 for @spikey_richie, I suspect it's the `CDbl(Date)` is not returning a date in a format the criteria likes...

Comment: @gns100 could be. It could be wrapped in an `isdate` check

Comment: @gns100 - what format would be required for it to work? The standard date format here is the dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Any date format, as long as Excel sees it as a date. You've put `cdbl(date)` which is casting the date as a double. Today (22/06/2022) shows as 44734, when cast as a double. That's not a date. Try it without casting the date as a double.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Turns out, a different filter i set right before the Date filter (one where i only showed Cells w/o coloured fill) messed up the results. When I switched them out, the Cdbl(Date) worked flawlessly.

Comment: So now your message box has a reasonable-looking number?

Comment: @spikey_richie yes - now the MsgBox displayes the correct number. Thanks!

Comment: @TrynRealHard In that case, add the steps taken to an answer, and submit it. You can then mark is as the correct answer, and others can benefit from your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different filter in the worksheet prevented the date filter to display the correct result. The CDbl(Date) criteria worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).